# How can I convert a dataframe that contains geometries to an sf object?

Tags: r, sf

1. I have an sf object that contains X line segment geometries, but has no columns of attribute data.
2. I have a separate dataframe that contains all the attribute data in the same order as the geometries.
3. When I combine the two using cbind, I get a dataframe that contains the geometries column
4. I need to intersect these geometries with geometries in another object. They both have the same number of rows.

The problem I have is after I do the cbind, the object class = "data.frame". As I result, I can't set the CRS or intersect it with an object of class=sf.

I've tried st_as_sf, but the class remains - "data.frame".

Comment: Can you show your actual code and information about your data and intermediate stages? doing a `cbind(sf_df, plain_df)` should produce an `sf_df`, and `cbind(plain_df, sf_df)` should produce a `plain_df` which when wrapped with `st_as_sf` should produce a spatial data frame. Without seeing your code we can't really see what you are doing and where it might be wrong.

Comment: I solved the problem using st_bind_cols